# Fullcalendar add and remove eventSources

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar-4

I have a problem with adding and removing eventSources using checkboxes. I feed Fullcalendar with whole eventSources Json array using JS var. This is because I need to generate feed according to user role. Unfortunately it works correctly only first time. I would be grateful for any tips.

feed:

```
    var eS;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/feed.php",
  }).done(function(result){
       eS = JSON.parse(result);
  });
```

output:

```
[{"color":"silver","editable":"1","events":[{"id":"e1","title":"Event 1","start":"2020-01-01","end":"2020-01-01"}]},{"color":"blue","editable":"1","events":[{"id":"e2","title":"Event 2","start":"2020-01-02","end":"2020-01-02"}]},{"color":"green","editable":"1","events":[{"id":"e3","title":"Event 3","start":"2020-01-03","end":"2020-01-03"}]},{"color":"yellow","editable":"1","events":[{"id":"e4","title":"Event 4","start":"2020-01-04","end":"2020-01-04"},{"id":"e5","title":"Event 5","start":"2020-01-05","end":"2020-01-05"}]},{"color":"pink","editable":"1","events":[{"id":"e6","title":"Event 6","start":"2020-01-06","end":"2020-01-06"}]}]
```

Fullcalendar:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'bootstrap'],  
      header: {
        left: 'promptResource today prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'timeGridYear,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
      },
      eventSources: eS
    });
    calendar.render();

var evS = calendar.getEventSources();
$("#allcalendars").on('change', 'input[id^="x"]', function() {
    var val = $(this).attr('id').replace('x', '');
    if (this.checked) {
        calendar.addEventSource(eS[val]);
    } else {
        evS[val].remove();
    }
    calendar.refetchEvents();
});
});
```

checkboxes

```
    <ul id="allcalendars">
        <input type="checkbox"id="x0" checked="checked">
        </li>
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="x1" checked="checked">
        </li>
...
</ul>
```

**Simulation:**
https://codepen.io/ketna11/pen/mdyQjxP

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: I have added codepen.

Comment: Your codepen appears to work fine, so what's the issue? If it's AJAX-related, you'll need to debug that yourself, because we can't run your AJAX request.

Comment: P.S. I don't think you need to run `calendar.refetchEvents();` after you add and remove event sources...fullCalendar will do this anyway as a natural consequence of updating the list of sources.

Comment: Unfortunately it works only first time. Try to check and uncheck checkbox twice. In codepen I did not used ajax. I suspect that this is fullcalendar bug. If you put url to events (url: '...') in Json instead of events array (events: [...]) it works correctly.